# How to run an observable function in the template?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, observable

I have presence service which shows the offline and online user

```
 // Presence Service
 getPresence(uid: string) {
    return this.db.object(`status/${uid}`).valueChanges();
 }
```

in the component template, I can run like this and get online user

```
<div *ngIf="presence$ | async as presence" 
    class="tag is-large" 
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-success':  presence.status  === 'online',
                 'is-warning': presence.status  === 'away',
                 'is-danger':  presence.status  === 'offline'
                 }"
>{{ presence.status }}</div>
```

but I want to use `getPresence(uid: string)` function in template like this:

```
<div *ngIf="presence.getPresence('CdceTHTS5we4TRsbYE7z8bDiZbx1') | async"
    class="tag is-large" 
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-success':  presence?.status  === 'online',
                 'is-warning': presence?.status  === 'away',
                 'is-danger':  presence?.status  === 'offline'
}">dffhghhhh</div>
```

Nothing happen. How can I use this observable function `getPresence(uid: string)` in template

Answer (score 1):

You will need to expose the `presence$` observable on your component. You can do the following:

```js
export class MyComponent {
    presence$ = this.presenceService.getPresence("myteamId");

    constructor(private presenceService: PresenceService) {}
}
```

If you expose the observable on your component class in this way, your first template should work.

Comment: I need to use this.presenceService.getPresence("myteamId") directly in template in html. your answer is work. but I try to use function direct in html. besouse I am getting uid in *ngfor

Comment: If you need to use it like this then redesign your app. You never know when change detection runs and this causes the statement in *ngIf to be evaluated again. and i doubt u wanna do that everytime

Comment: yes finki as your doupt I wanna do that everytime. thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use a object cache for this or you'll be getting an new observable everytime when the component is repainted. This way you can keep using function call but always get the corresponding userStatus stream

```
getPresence(uid: string) {
    this.userStatus[uid]=this.usersStatus[uid]?this.usersStatus[uid]:
    this.db.object(`status/${uid}`).valueChanges();
    return this.userStatus[uid]
 }
```

another alternative is suppose you will have the users object fetched in your component and you can create the status observable before passing to view

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.users=http.get('users').pipe(map(users=>{
       return this.users.map(user=>({...user,status:presence.getPresence(user.id)}))
    }))
}
```

in your view

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users | async ">
    <div *ngIf="user.status | async as presence" 
       .....
```